# How to install miktex on Pop! OS 20.10?

Tags: installing, ubuntu, linux

I tried installing Miktex on Pop! Os 20.10 through the terminal according to the method on this link https://miktex.org/download, but an error occurs as follows

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested 
an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that 
some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of 
Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: miktex : Depends: libicu66 
(>= 66.1-1~) but it is not installable
 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: A quick google reveals that Pop! OS *may* have libicu65 installed rather than libicu66. You may have better luck asking on stack overflow about getting libicu66 installed.